# File structure explorer (sth like Wireshark, but for files)

Tags: file, analysis, file-type, decomposition

I am looking for a software which is able to **decompose** and **analyze files**. Do you know any?

What I mean is something that, given a file, would tell me for example:

- here is the **magic number telling that it is a PNG**, and here starts a **colors definition**, here goes the **compression flag**, and then there are the picture data, and so on...

or something like:

- this is a MP3 file, here is the **ID3 definition**, here is the **flag** telling that this is the **joint stereo** and so on...

I am looking for a software **doing with files** what **Wireshark** (Ethereal) is doing with **network traffic**.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is such an app. The only easy possible solution is to have some syntax file and some script using it. But I believe, it is easier to write this script+syntax database by yourself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software [HexWorkshop](http://www.hexworkshop.com/) is a commercial hex editor which has a "Data interpretation" mode in which each fields of a data structure is highlighted in the editor. It comes with a (very) few definitions of data structures or file format but you can easily write your own.

I used to use a very old version (several years ago) and this software has helped me a lot for several reverse engineering projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'file' command on unix boxes (or else under mingw or cygwin) to determine the type of a file. This will look up the magic numbers for the types that are known. But no extra information will be provided.

I don't know of any software that has the whole knowledge of all the file formats as to provide further insights (sections in the file).